# How do I dynamically add some piece of php code to an exact position in page before it is returned to the browser?

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, gravity

I need to add this piece of code right before my `wp_head();` call using PHP because the code has to execute server side. Hooking the code into my `wp_head();` does not work. I need to add it right before. Here is the PHP code to be added.

```
gravity_form_enqueue_scripts(1,true);
```

Here is where the code needs to be inserted:

```
<?php

/* We add some JavaScript to pages with the comment form
 * to support sites with threaded comments (when in use).
 */
if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

/* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
 * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
 * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
 * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
 */

gravity_form_enqueue_scripts(1,true);

wp_head(); ?>
```

The code should not show on return to browser. How do I add this PHP snippet to this exact location dynamically?

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a combination of jQuery and PHP ?

Comment: Maybe I should hook it into another action in wordpress ?

Answer (score 1):

I actually needed to :

```
add_action('wp', 'gforms_add_before_wp_head');
```

not

```
add_action('wp_head', 'gforms_add_before_wp_head');
```

I turns out I just needed to find the right hook to add_action to.